# Macbook Pro can only boot into EFI, how can I transfer files to my Macbook Air?

Tags: macos, mac, startup, file-transfer, efi

I have recently upgraded Disk Utility on my Macbook Pro. Now my device only boots into Recovery Mode and when I hold alt/option I can only see EFI. When I try to get into safe mode, I see a "No Symbol".

How can I transfer files from my Macbook Pro that will only boot into EFI to my Macbook Air that is fully functioning.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "upgraded Disk Utility"  Did you upgrade your *operating system*?   Also, what do you mean it only boots into EFI (EFI is not something you boot *into*)?  What (besides the prohibitory symbol) are you seeing?  Can you post a photo?

Comment: In addition to the questions and photo @Allan is asking for, it may be worth adding other details to your question such as the exact models of your MBP and MBA, as well as the version of macOS you have running on the MBP. Basically, the best option for transferring your files will depend on the models you own.

Comment: @Allan It boots into the same thing that you will boot into by holding ⌘R.

Comment: That's *Recovery*, not EFI.  See [About macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

Comment: I would certainly try target mode before you start taking apart anything.  Connect your Mac to another Mac (one of your old ones, a friends), using thunderbolt / FireWire, and see if the original drive is accessible.  If you don’t have another machine handy, then use advice below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, perhaps the terminology you are using is not accurate. Like calling "Recovery Mode" "EFI" which it most certainly is not.

If all you need from the MacBook Pro is the data off the drive, you can remove the SSD or HD from the unit, put it in a USB enclosure and get you data and apps off it that way, possibly even using the Migration Assistant app which will work on an external drive that used to be internal.

Ifixit.com is a good source for take-apart instructions for most current and many older Macs, if you need help dissembling...

Comment: I'll try this when my USB enclosure comes in the mail. I'll accept the answer in it works.

Comment: Could I copy these files onto another hard drive and then boot from it?

Comment: There are programs (Carbon Copy Cloner, SuperDuper) that will clone one drive to another. Be aware that simply copying (system) files in the Finder will not work.